# Retain DataGridView metadata after clearing DataSource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, datagridview

I have `DataGridView` that has a `var` collection resulting from a `LINQ` `join` between two database objects. I select only certain columns from the resulting join and feed it as a `DataSource` property to my `DataGridView`. The metadata of my `DataGridView` is adapted to the columns of the `var` object and applies formatting at runtime.

The problem is when I need to clear the content and feed new `var` with my `join` result. If I code `DataGridView.DataSource = null` I will clear the content but also destroy metadata. Next time I feed my `var` collection, the formatting will be all messed up. 

The question is how to clear data-bound `DataGridView` content and retain its original metadata?
I guess I could feed empty `var` collection modelled after my joined objects but is there a native `DataGridView` method that would clear the content and retain column structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define columns for your `DataGridView` and set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false` then your grid only shows the columns that you defined. Also even after you set the `DataSource` to null it keeps columns.

Example:

In the below example, the grid only shows Property1 and Property2 in grid. Also if you set the data source to null, the grid keeps the columns.

```
var column1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
column1.DataPropertyName = "Property1";
column1.HeaderText = "Column1";

var column2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
column2.DataPropertyName = "Property2";
column2.HeaderText = "Column2";

this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column1);
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column2);

this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                                            .Select(x => new 
                                            { 
                                                Property1 = x,
                                                Property2 = x, 
                                                Property3 = x
                                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for! Worked great. Funny, I read your post just after I had cleated method utilizing empty source, hehe, now I have two ways of clearing that control but yours is more RAM-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```